# Cannot store image in internal storage

Tags: android, file, storage

I'm trying to store some images, that I get as base64 coded strings, in the internal storage.
For some reason they don't seem to be stored, and I have no clue why.

This is the function that stores them:

```
public void createImage(String image, String name){
    try{
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap img_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

        //mCtx is the context. It comes from the main activity
        FileOutputStream fos = mCtx.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        img_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        //Let's check if they're there
        File f = new File(mCtx.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + name + ".png");

        if (f.exists())
             Log.v(DB_TAG, "Exists");
        else
             Log.v(DB_TAG, "Not exists");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(DB_TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

I keep getting "Not exists" in the logcat. Why can that be?

Comment: you cant write to the internal storage.  unless this is a honeycomb tablet

Comment: why? It doesn't say anything about that in the android dev-site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: are you sure about the path u passing to File()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File f = new File(mCtx.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + name); //<-- removed .png!
if (f.exists())
    Log.v(DB_TAG, "Exists");
else
    Log.v(DB_TAG, "Not exists");
```

You are saving your file as 'name' and then, the file you created as 'name.png'.

Comment: Wow, it does exist. Then I have a worse problem :S
Why don't you have to put the ".png"?
Thanks for que quick help. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Because you are using: `mCtx.openFileOutput(name` then it saves the file with that name. It does not matter if you encode it as PNG, the file extension is not important at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are some know issues with BitmapFactory decodeByteArray (for example with PNGs - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956641/png-base64-decoding-problem-in-android). It would be worth logging the bitmap returned from decodeByteArray with

```
Log.v(DB_TAG, "Bitmap = " + bitmap);
```

to see if it's non-null.

Comment: This is what I get "Bitmap = android.graphics.Bitmap@48169658". Is that what should be there?

Comment: Yes... That means the bitmap exists. You would see "null" if it did not. But I'm sure Cristian's answer below is correct. You're saving "name" and trying to read "name.png". Sorry I didn't spot that.